# Spring boot generating fat jar with dependencies explicitly excluded

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-3, dependency-management, java-11

I have a dependency in my pom that excludes a transitive dependency as shown below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But when I generate my dependency tree I get the following:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ system-infrastructure ---
br.com.site.system:system-infrastructure:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
+- br.com.site.system:system-core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
|  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
|  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
|  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
|  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.5:runtime
|     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.5:runtime
|     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:runtime
|     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
+- io.projectreactor:reactor-test:jar:3.4.12:test
|  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.12:compile
|     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
+- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.1:test
|  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
|  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.1:test
|  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
+- org.mockito:mockito-inline:jar:4.0.0:test
|  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0:test
|     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22:test
|     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22:test
|     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
+- org.pitest:pitest-junit5-plugin:jar:0.15:test
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.6.1:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.13:compile
|  |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.13:compile
|  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.13:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.7:compile
|  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.7:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:compile
|  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
|  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.1:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.1:test
|  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:test
|  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:test
|  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:test
|  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
|  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile
|  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
|  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
|  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.21.0:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
|  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.1:test
|  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.1:test
|  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.1:test
|  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.1:test
|  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.0.0:test
|  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
|  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.13:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.13:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.13:test
|  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.3:test
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.0:compile
|  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
|     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
|     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.55:compile
|  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.0.Final:compile
|     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
|     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
|     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.0:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.0:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.6.1:compile
|  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.13:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.13:compile
|  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.13:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.13:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.13:compile
+- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:7.0.1:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.0:compile
|     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.0:compile
|     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.0:compile
+- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-core:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  \- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.1.11:compile
|  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.11:compile
|  |     +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-integration:jar:2.1.11:compile
|  |     |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.1.11:compile
|  |     |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.13.0:compile
|  |     \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.116:compile
|  +- org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:4.1.3:compile
|  \- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.48:compile
\- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
```

Which leads me to two different questions:

1. Shouldn't all the dependencies in a dependency scoped as test be excluded in the final fat jar? I ask that because `jakarta.xml.bind-api` is a transitive dependency to my micro service and a compile dependency to `spring-boot-starter-test` which is a direct and test-scoped dependency to my micro service but `jakarta.xml.bind-api` appears in my dependency tree as a compile dependency.
2. Even though I explicitly exclude `jakarta.xml.bind-api` as shown above, it appears in my dependency tree shown above and in my final jar as shown
   below: [image: JAXB dependencies]

Am I missing something about how spring-boot generates its fat jar or is it actually a bug?

Comment: No. You excluded it from one dependency but it still can be part of another. Excluding it from one doesn't exclude it for other dependencies. It is part of `spring-boot-starter` which is the parent of all spring boot starters. So unless excluded from `spring-boot-starter` explicitly it will be pulled in by others again.

Comment: The dependency is coming from org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test base on the given output (assumed that is the full output)...my assumption is that get it through another dependency...

Comment: @M.Deinum, Eclipse added the exclusion in every dependency for me. I just showed the first one.

Comment: @khmarbaise That's one of my doubts, even thought it is compile-scoped to `spring-boot-starter-test`, shouldn't it not be included in my final jar since `spring-boot-starter-test` is test scoped to my micro service?

Comment: Then check the whole tree and not only part...what also comes into my mind is: How is spring boot maven plugin configured?

Comment: @khmarbaise you mean the Eclipse plugin? I just installed it and did not customize it.

Comment: No I meant the spring boot maven plugin in your pom configuration...

Comment: @khmarbaise I figured out what was happening, my project is splitted into maven modules. I was excluding from one module but I was checking mistenkenly the other. Should I delete this question?